# hmodule in D5 willl not complie

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, twebbrowser

I have incoming text from `FieldByName(aFld).AsString` that may sometimes contain HTML tags.  I want to parse the text and use something like this to display it:

[How to load and save documents in TWebBrowser in a Delphi-like way](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=14)

If the text has HTML tags, I'd like any URLs to be highlighted. They need not work as clickable, but visually this is what I am after.

The component in the article comes with a D6+ example program, but it is balking at `HModule`. I can't compile in D5 as it does not seem to recognize `HModule`.  What is it? How do I get around it?

I tried using TWebBrowser and the following but the Tags do not get highlighted to look like they are clickable.

[How to load HTML directly to a WebBrowser](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0104_4.htm)

Comment: personally, I don't understand the *question*. is the whole story about the `TWebBrowser` even relevant here?

Comment: It is a data type for a module handle. The code you found uses it to load html from a resource.

Comment: Trying lots of different ways to load the doc into a browser control won't help you. If the browser doesn't display the document the way you hope for then doing the same thing again won't change it. You need to understand why the browser control doesn't do what you want it to with your document.

Answer (score 1):

`HModule` is declared in the `Windows` unit.  Make sure that unit is in your `uses` clause.